# How to insert two different array values into a table in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert the values of two arrays into a table in a single query . Is it possible to do something like that.

table format

```
id | product_id | category_id | blog_id | updated_by | created_date
```

**category _id**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 18
)
```

**Product_id**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2260 
    [1] => 1401 
)

Blog id = mysql_insert_id();
```

result

```
id | product_id | category_id | blog_id | updated_by  
 1      2260        4               15      xyz         
 2      1401        15              15      xyz   
 3      null        18              15      xyz
```

Any suggestions for me also to improve the better insert query for this.

Comment: what you have tried? how u r doing this right now?

Comment: i have tried writing insert queries into the two times for two arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `Table_Name` (`product_id`, `category_id`, `blog_id`, `updated_by`) VALUES (2260, 4, 15, 'xyz'), (1401, 15, 15, 'xyz'), (, 18, 15, 'xyz');
```

I assumed that `id` column is an auto incremented one.

Comment: @Ragavendran Ramesh: Its good, you need to append the query values by iterating your both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple rows at one go in the same query that you are using now. Just add a comma, and put in more values:

```
Insert into myTable values ('field1-var1','field2-var2'), ('field1-var2','field2-var2') ..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$combain = array_merge($cat , $proid);   
for($i = 0; $i <count($combain); $i++ )
            {
                if(isset($proid[$i])) {
                    $product_id = $proid[$i];
                }
                else{
                    $product_id = "''";
                }            
                if(isset($cat[$i])){
                    $category_id = $cat[$i];
                }
                else{
                    $category_id = "''";
                }   
                if(!empty($cat[$i]) || !empty($proid[$i])) {

                    @$values[] ="('',". $blogid.",".$category_id.",".$product_id.","."'".$updated_by."'".",now())";
                }
            }        
            $query = $this->db->query("insert into blog_details (id , blog_id , cat_id, pro_id, updated_by , created_date) values" . implode(',', $values));
```